# Merge values and Bind dynamically in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having Output in a dialogbox in the format as

```
 ODS
 1234|Hyd
 ODS
 1234|Blore
 ODS
 6847|Pune
 CDS
 1234|Chenni
 CDS
 4854|Delhi
```

Here I wanted to merge all ODC and CDS and wanted to show Output in the below format

```
ODS
1234|Hyd
1234|Blore
6847|Pune
CDS
1234|Chenni
4854|Delhi
```

I have tried in diff ways like..

```
    UserAccessPE Contains Values EX: Program = ODS,CDS, MPNID = 1234,6789, Geography = 'Hyd','Pune' ..., In these way
     var programtemp = "";
     var MPNIDtemp = "";

   for (var i = 0; i < UserAccessPE.length; i++) {
        if (UserAccessPE[i].program == UserAccessPE[i + 1].program) {
                programtemp = '<br><div class="Programdiv"> <span> <br>' + UserAccessPE[i].program + '<br /></span></div><br />';

                for (var j = 0 ; j < UserAccessPE.length; j++) {
                    MPNIDtemp = ' <br><div class="mpniddiv"> <span><br>' + UserAccessPE[i].MPNID + ' |  ' + UserAccessPE[i].Geography + '<br/></span></div><br /> ';
                }

                $("#UserAccessDiv").append(programtemp);
                $("#UserAccessDiv").append(MPNIDtemp);


        }

    }
```

Please help me..., I am almost done in Binding values dynamic but unable to merge same values and bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not already in the right order, you need to ensure that the source array is sorted on the `.program` property:

```
UserAccessPE.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.program < b.program;
});
```

Then build output as an array of HTML fragments, exploiting `array.reduce()` to perform the looping and to give you the previous value :

```
var html = [];
UserAccessPE.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    if(!prev || current.program !== prev.program) {
        html.push('<div class="mdiv Programdiv">' + current.program + '</div>');
    }
    html.push('<div class="mdiv mpniddiv">' + current.MPNID + ' | ' + current.Geography + '</div>');
    return current;
}, null);

// join HTML fragments and append
$("#UserAccessDiv").append(html.join(''));
```

The HTML in the question is simplified here to avoid the double div wrap and the `<br>`s, both of which appear to be unnecessary. By all means re-complicate as desired.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4awmj6hj/)**

Not too sure what you mean by "binding" but from what you say, you seem to have it under control.